# querySelector null in iframe when readyState is complete

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that I append to the body. I want to get an element inside the iframe.
Nothing difficult, I just add a `querySelector` like this `iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#test')`. To make it works, I have to wait the iframe to be loaded. Hence, I just add an eventListener load on the iframe and it works like a charme.

However, what I was wondering is why at first glance, the element that I tried to get is `null` whereas the `readyState` is `complete`. Indeed, the document has finished loading and parsed when `readyState` is `interactive`. So I make the assumption that when it is `complete`, it has been done and the element should be in the document.
In addition, I have no script, no image, no stylesheet. [See MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

So why the querySelector is null when readyState is complete? (see the reproducible example in JSFiddle, does not work in snippet)

```
const srcdoc = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
`;

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded', iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState);
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded', iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#test'));
});

iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('onLoad', iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState);
  console.log('onLoad', iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#test'));
});

iframe.srcdoc = srcdoc;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

console.log('init', iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState);
console.log('init', iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#test'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably figured out, these two statements are executed before the *new* document has been loaded into the `iframe`.

```
console.log('init', iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState);
console.log('init', iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#test'));
```

The reason the `readyState` is already `complete` is the `iframe` has a content document when it is created, well before the new content -- with the test element -- has been loaded.

You can demonstrate this by adding this line:

```
    console.log('init', iframe.contentWindow.document);
```

The iframe's document at that point is `about:blank`.

Comment: So the readyState for the iframe is not really a property on which we can trust?

Comment: You can rely on it, but it doesn’t mean that a document has finished loading into an `iframe`. The `onload` event seems to do what you want, though. You could leverage that, maybe by having the code in the iframe trigger a custom event that the main page listens for?

Comment: In fact, my main point is to find a way that the load event has been already fired to avoid to add the onLoad event listener

Comment: I see. I have no answer for that. Maybe another question?

Comment: It does not seem to have an answer for that from what I looked. The only solution is too add like a variable to know if the loaded has been fired.